# Looking up data from a file, and storing them as variables

Tags: autohotkey

I'm new to autohotkey and I can't figure out how to solve this. Any help is appreciated.
I have list.txt which includes ids and names like this:

```
list.txt:
123124 - whatever
834019 - sometext
3980   - afjalkfj
```

I need a function that can do the following

```
lookup(id, name){
    ** The function here should lookup for the id inserted 
 then save ONLY the data related to it in variable x (not the full line)
}
```

Example

```
lookup(834019, x)
%x% = sometext
```

Please help me to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need in this case are

- [FileRead](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileRead.htm) to read the file's contents into a variable.
- A [parsing loop](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopParse.htm) to parse the text of each line.
- The [StrSplit()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringSplit.htm) function to split the text of each line into an 
  array of Substrings using the specified Delimiters.

The second parameter (name) is redundant in this case. You can omit it:

```
x := lookup(834019)
MsgBox, % x

MsgBox, % lookup(3980)


lookup(id) {
    FileRead, Contents, list.txt   ; read the file's contents into the variable "Contents"
    if not ErrorLevel  ; Successfully loaded.
    {
        Loop, parse, Contents, `n, `r  ; parse the text of each line 
        {
            word_array1 := StrSplit(A_LoopField," - ").1  ; store the first substring into the variable "word_array1"
            word_array1 := Trim(word_array1, " `t") ; trim spaces and tabs in this variable
            If (word_array1 = id)
            {
                name := StrSplit(A_LoopField," - ").2
                name := Trim(name, " `t")
                return name
            }
        }
        Contents := ""  ; Free the memory.
    }
    else
        MsgBox, A problem has been encountered while loading the File Contents
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me a lot.
My only issue now is that I want the information to be stored inside the second parameter (name)
For example if I run
lookup(100000004, name1)
And use %name1% later in the script it would still show the name